# Volver a la actividad padre

Tags: java, android, android-intent

En manifest.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <activity
        android:name="ActividadA">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ActividadB"
        android:parentActivityName="ActividadA">
    </activity>
```

Hay alguna manera sencilla de volver a una actividad padre que no sea la típica de:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, ActividadA.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Mirate ese tutorial https://dev4phones.wordpress.com/2016/09/09/patron-de-navegacion-en-android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La manera de volver a la `Activity` principal mediante un `Intent`, en realidad no es típica, regularmente la `Activity` padre no se vuelve a abrir con un `Intent`, aunque se puede realizar mediante:

```
intent = new Intent(MyOtraActivity.this , MyMainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

En cambio las Activity secundarias, regularmente son abiertas mediante un `Intent` y estas son acumuladas en el Back Stack.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas regresar a una Activity anterior, simplemente finalizas en la que te encuentras mediante `finish();` con lo cual se destruye la activity Actual.

Actualmente no es buena practica apilar varias Activity en el Back Stack ya que podríamos tener principalmente problemas con memoria, para esta función se crearon los Fragments los cuales son abiertos dentro de una Activity sin tener que almacenar diferentes Activity en el Back Stack, sería un diseño incorrecto seguir usando varias Activity y que sean apiladas una tras de otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función `finish()` la cual llamará al método `onDestroy` de tu `Actividad` actual. Es decir, si llamas a una Actividad desde tu Actividad padre y usas esta función desde la Actividad hijo, volverás a la Actividad padre de nuevo.

Comment: Esa función me puede funcionar en algún caso, pero por ejemplo si tengo 3 actividades: A, B y C.  Si voy desde A hasta C y después quiero volver hasta la actividad A  utilizando finish(); es imposible, porque cuando esté en B me volverá a C que es la actividad anterior.

Comment: Cierto si funciona, antes no funcionaba porque estaba haciendo algo raro al cambiar de actividad xD  gracias

Comment: @borjis De nada :). Por favor, considera aceptar la respuesta si te ha resuelto el problema. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Si en el `manifest.xml` especificas el `parentActivityName` puedes llamar `navigateUpFromSameTask` de las `NavUtils`

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

Usando eso, tiene la particularidad que cuando se vuelve a la `ActividadA` se recarga de nuevo.

Mírate las siguientes entradas:

- La documentación oficial [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
- [Tutorial de sistema de navegación basica](https://dev4phones.wordpress.com/2016/09/09/patron-de-navegacion-en-android/)